# Can /EHa exception option be used with c++20 module?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-options, c++-modules

I know that the documentation says that "To consume the Microsoft Standard Library modules, compile your program with /EHsc and /MD options." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170

But I desperately hope that /EHa can be used and wish, in a naive way, that there is something that can be done that isn't changing the /EHa option.

Because I work on an application with millions of code lines with hundreds of other persons. We use the /EHa to catch uncatched exception and generate a log with the callstack. I don't think that changing the compiler options is an option. But I think using modules will help us with our headers trouble in c++/CLI.

Ask in others words, maybe /EHa is compatible with code compiled with /EHsc but not the other way around?

Comment: I guess it's because that's how MS built the modules (for the Standard Library) see [__Important__](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-170) - _"...We recommend that you never link object files compiled using /EHa to ones compiled using /EHs or /EHsc in the same executable module. ..."_

Comment: Also even though MS provides modules for the Standard Library it still calls this an experiential feature see: [Overview of modules in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) _"...To enable support for Standard Library modules, compile with __/experimental:module__ and /std:c++latest..."_ So it's probably best to avoid in production code for a while.

Comment: You right about the experimental part and I guess we won't be using it for a while. But I think we can still create our own modules for problematic headers ( meaning headers that include MS threading headers which can't be compiled in c++/CLI) and still use /EHa.

Comment: What they are *actually* saying is "These modules may throw exceptions, you need to enable exception handling".  You can use /EHa, it also enables exception handling.